# In cargo, is there a way to specify package dependencies and workspace dependencies in one place?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am experimenting with a workspace directory structure where I have a `src` and `crates` folder in my project root. The `crates` folder consists of workspace members and the project root `src/` contains a library that's shared among the workspace members in `crates/*`.

For the `crates/*` I use inherited dependencies like `x = { workspace = true }`. Before introducing the `crates/*` workspace members, I would have all my dependencies under `[dependencies]` in the root `./Cargo.toml`. After introducing workspace members, for me to be able to use inherited dependencies I must place all these (inheritable) dependencies under `[workspace.dependencies]`.

The problem is that I am duplicating dependencies as my `$PROJECT_ROOT/src` looks for `[dependencies]` and the workspace members require their dependencies to live under `[workspace.dependencies]`.

Is there a way to have them both under one tag? There is no other problem other than this setup looking a bit less elegant than I would've preferred.

Here's the setup in code :

```ini
# ROOT/Cargo.toml
[workspace]
members = ["crates/kvs-client", "crates/kvs-server"]

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.1.6", features = ["derive"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
env_logger = "0.10.0"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
log = "0.4.20"
ron = "0.8.1"
serde = { version = "1.0.188", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.104"
thiserror = "1.0.38"

[workspace.dependencies]
kvs = { path = "." }
clap = { version = "4.1.6", features = ["derive"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
env_logger = "0.10.0"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
log = "0.4.20"
ron = "0.8.1"
```

Comment: You can use the same `x = { workspace = true }` syntax as in sub packages in the main package, but imho it's preferable to not mix a workspace with a package.